# Redirect in silverlight 5, having problems

Tags: c#, silverlight, redirect, silverlight-5.0

I've seen on quite a few site the following being used

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://silverlight.net"), "_blank");
```

but I get an error that says its failed to invoke: open

How do I redirect in SL 5?

Comment: Have you tried other browsers?  Can you provide more details about the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `EnableHtmlAccess` setting? link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838264%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Otherwise, could you post any additional details of the error message?

Comment: if I set the place where the link should be opened to "_self" it works perfectly but doesn't want to open n new page. im using IE 10